# How to make whole screen scrollable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with the whole screen scrolling in Flutter. Only the Expanded widget is able to scroll on-screen in my app but I want to make the whole screen scrollable. How can I do that? Here is my code e.g.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'My App',
        style: AppTheme.of(context).title1,
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
    ),
    body: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 20, 10, 0),
          child: Column(


        . // Padding repeats two more times
        . 
        .
        .

        Expanded(
            child: MyWidget(
                myProp1: value1,
                myProp2: value2,
                myProp3: value3,
                myProp4: value4,
                myProp5: value5,
                myProp6: value6
            ) // MyWidget
        ), // Expanded
      ],
    ), // Column
  ); // Scaffold
}
```

I've tried to wrap **Column** with `SingleChildScrollview` widget but it didn't work for me. I guess I can not use **Expanded** widget in SingleChildScrollview. I also tried to use **Container** or etc. instead of **Expanded** and **Column** widgets but I couldn't solve this issue. Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap `MyWidget` with `Expanded`. Just Change `Column` into `ListView`:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'My App',
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 20, 10, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 500,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 500,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ), // Column
    ); // Scaffold
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I changed `Column` into `ListView` and I wrap `MyWidget` with only `SizedBox`. If I use **MyWidget** without **SizedBox** even though I changed **Column** into **ListView** I'm getting this error:
`RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: It's bit hard to understand since I dont know content of the MyWidget but possible reason is Column expects his height to be given by its parent. So you either specify it by giving SizedBox or wrap it by Expanded to show that it can expand any available space it wants to

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the SingleChildScroll view as Child of Expanded widget will work fine